# MySQL - SELECT MAX(), and get corresponding fields

Tags: mysql

The task is: get the list with ID of every employee and the ID of the last department where he worked. It's becoming more complicated cause one person can work in different departments at one time, so we need to get his last department where he has the max rate.

table:

```
 ID_employee| ID_department | end_date  |   rate
 1            22              2016-01-01    1
 2            25              NULL          0.3
 2            27              NULL          1
 3            22              2013-12-12    0.5
 3            22              2014-05-05    0.5
```

`end_date` is the last day when employee worked, and NULL value means that his contract is actual today.

The result must look like:

```
ID_employee | ID_department | end_date  |   rate
1             22              2016-01-01    1
2             27              NULL          1
3             22              2014-05-05    0.5
```

I found out how to select max() with corresponding fields by using join:

```
SELECT table.id_employee, id_department
FROM table
JOIN (  SELECT id_employee,
    IF (MAX( end_date IS NULL ) = 1 , "0000-00-00",  MAX( end_date )) as max_end_date
    FROM table GROUP BY id_employee) maxs ON maxs.id_employee = table.id_employee
WHERE maxs.max_end_date = IFNULL(table.end_date, "0000-00-00")
GROUP BY table.id_employee
```

However, there are ALL corresponding rows in the result:

```
ID_employee | ID_department | end_date  |   rate
1             22              2016-01-01    1
2             25              NULL          0.3
2             27              NULL          1
3             22              2014-05-05    0.5
```

The question is, how to get NOT JUST corresponding rows to MAX(end_date), but with MAX(rate) too? I assume that HAVING might help, but I still don't know what exactly must be there.

And maybe there are other ways to solve problem with better performance, because this query works about 16s while the table has ~30 000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with the query below:

```
SELECT  T1.ID_employee,  
        T1.ID_department, 
        CASE WHEN maxs.max_end_date = "0000-00-00" THEN NULL ELSE maxs.max_end_date END AS end_date, 
        T1.rate
FROM TestTable T1
JOIN (  SELECT  id_employee,
                MAX(ID_department) AS ID_department,
                IF (MAX( end_date IS NULL ) = 1, "0000-00-00",  MAX( end_date )) AS max_end_date
        FROM TestTable 
        GROUP BY id_employee ) maxs ON maxs.id_employee = T1.id_employee AND maxs.ID_department = T1.ID_department
WHERE maxs.max_end_date = IFNULL(T1.end_date, "0000-00-00")
GROUP BY T1.id_employee
```

Please find the <kbd>[`Live Demo`](http://rextester.com/PPF73311)</kbd>

**UPDATE:**

As per the comments the following query helped to achieve the result:

```
SET @CurrentDate := CURDATE();

SELECT T2.ID_employee, 
       T2.ID_department, 
       CASE WHEN MR.Max_end_date = @CurrentDate THEN NULL ELSE T2.end_date END AS end_date, 
       MR.MaxRate AS rate
FROM TestTable T2 
JOIN (
    SELECT T1.ID_employee, MAX(T1.rate) AS MaxRate, MD.Max_end_date
    FROM TestTable T1
    JOIN (
        SELECT  ID_employee,
                MAX(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN @CurrentDate ELSE end_date END) AS Max_end_date
        FROM TestTable 
        GROUP BY ID_employee
        ) MD ON MD.ID_employee = T1.ID_employee
    WHERE MD.Max_end_date = IFNULL(T1.end_date, @CurrentDate)
    GROUP BY T1.ID_employee
) MR ON MR.ID_employee = T2.ID_employee AND MR.MaxRate = T2.rate 
WHERE MR.Max_end_date = IFNULL(T2.end_date, @CurrentDate)
```

<kbd>[`Working Demo`](http://rextester.com/RXGU80720)</kbd>

Comment: ​Arulkumar, there is one mistake in your solution: **MAX(ID_department)**. It doesn't make sense, cause it's just an identifier, a value without meaning, a primary key in another table. If we change **ID_department** in 3rd row from `27` to `23`, in the result for employee with identifier `2` we'll get `department 25, rate 0.3`, but the correct answer is `department 23 and rate 1`, because rate 1 is higher than 0.3.

Comment: I've replaced **ID_department** to **rate** and it helped, but the next problem appears. If someone previously (in the past) had a higher rate than now
(in following example - employee `2` worked to `December 12, 2013` with rate `1`; now he works at two departments with rates `0.3` and `0.7`) then no rows for this employee returned.
I would be grateful if you could check my example and maybe give me an advice, please.
[link to live demo](http://rextester.com/JLL5389)

Comment: @AnnieLinnik: Could you please check this [`DEMO`](http://rextester.com/KZMW23241). I have a question: For an example, for `ID_employee : 3`, the entries are `(3, 22, '2013-12-12',  0.7),
(3, 20, '2014-05-05',  0.5)` what is your expected result?

Comment: for `ID_employee: 3` expected result is `(3, 20, '2014-05-05', 0.5)`, because `end_date` here bigger than in `(3, 22, '2013-12-12', 0.7)`. But if dates were the same, result must be  `(3, 22, '2013-12-12', 0.7)` because of higher `rate`. Your demo looks fine, but for  `ID_employee: 2` result must be `(2, 25, NULL, 0.7)`: NULL here means 'today date', and rate 0.7 > 0.3.

Comment: @AnnieLinnik: I spent reasonable time to work-out to achieve expectation. But it required 2 `JOINS` to get the result. For getting the `MAX(end_date), MAX(Rate)` values, it needed 2 separate conditions. Please find the [`DEMO`](http://rextester.com/RXGU80720)

Comment: I guess this is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will work for you.

```
SELECT ID_employee, ID_department, end_date, MAX(rate)
 FROM test_max
 GROUP BY ID_employee
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question

Comment: This query returns first `ID_department`, first `end_date` and max `rate`, while I need corresponding `ID_department` to row with max or null `end_date` and maximum value of `rate` if there are a few rows with null `end_date` or the same max `end_date`. Sorry if my explanation above was not clear.